# How to specify exact path for save states in the Duckstation (PS1) emulator?

Tags: pc, emulation, ps1

With the [Duckstation](https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation) PS1 emulator,
assuming a Windows 10 installation, the default path of the save states is:
C:\Users\ (username) \Documents\DuckStation\savestates

I'd like to change the path of this "savestates" folder only so that it can be shared across multiple computers, as can already be done with the memory card save path.
Is there any way to do so?